# Why write of dataframe creates file with header and tail only?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (data7) that has 12678 rows. When I write it to txt file I get in the file only the header and the tail of the dataframe. Why is it? How can I write all the content of the dataframe into txt file? 
Here are the commands I use:

```
> nrow (data7)
[1] 12678
> location<-"C:/Data/"
> write(capture.output(data7), paste(location,"A123.txt"), append = TRUE)
```

Comment: Don't use `capture.output()` or `append = TRUE` there.  And you could also use `write.table()` instead.

Comment: This is the strangest way of writing a data.frame to file that I have seen in a while. Use `write.table` instead.

Comment: Why do this? Anyways, it sounds like you have a `data.table`, not a `data.frame`...

Comment: By the way, you can look at what the output will be first with `write(data, stdout())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all commenters, Here is the solution:

```
> location<-"C:/Data/"
> write.table (data7, paste(location,"A123.txt"))
```